# Google Translate Voice/Speech used for Youtube Tutorials (TTS)

Tags: copyright

I have made a video tutorial using Google Translates Voice/Speech-functionality to explain what the user should do. It works really good compered to other free open-sorce programs I have used.

Can I upload this to Youtube without legal consequences?

I am counting on earning a few bucks on the video so it's commerical use.

Comment: Related: https://ttsreader.com/blog/2017/05/10/copyright/

Answer (score 3):

The Google [terms of service](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) do not prohibit using their translate programs to create something that you sell. TOS for using their API would be irrelevant, since that isn't what you're doing. There is no clear copyright issue: as far as I can tell, there is not yet any case law suggesting that the output of a program can be owned by the copyright-holder of the program. (Copyright must be held by a legal person, i.e. an actual person or a corporation, and a program cannot yet be a legal person). A human-performed translation is subject to copyright protection since what is protected is that which is created by the (translating) author, and a program lacks that creative element. A translation owes its existence to the program-user using a particular tool to create the work, be it a pen or a translation program. What is unclear at present is whether a person using machine translation in a permitted fashion to create a derivative work thereby gains copyright to that derived work.